# onTouch event on Android Games

Tags: android, events, screen, touch-event

my question is not only about onTouch events but about every method I can use to recognise a touch on certain areas of the screen.

Right now, I have a "background" image, which I use as layout that contains 2 "buttons": Start and Options as you can see here:

[image]

Ok, what I want to know is which is the best way to identify when are the user touching each button. By the way, should be nice also some info about how to deal with the different screen sizes.

Lots of thanks.

PD: seems I didnt explain it well. they are not "Android buttons" theirselves. The background is a whole image, where you can find 2 "buttons", but they are a part of the image. Thats because I need to know how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're missing some fundamentals, so I recommend to [take a tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html) track.
As a direct answer to your question , you can see [this page](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) from the tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didnt explain it well. Read the top comment please.

Comment: If you're using low level graphics, than you know the pixel (dp) coordinates you draw the "buttons", and you get the pixel coordinates from the event, than you just need to loop on your model and check if the touch is inside.

Comment: Buff I though so, but I expected an easier way to deal with it because of the problem with the different device screen sizes... Anyway, thank you ^^

Comment: sure, no problem. If you want an easier solution, use the higher level API the platform gives you (hence the tutorial link). Going low level is fun, but all the nitty gritty is up to you to implement

Answer (score 0):

Why do you want to set the touchListener on whole screen and find the buttons?..You can simply set the OnClickListener or onTouchListener on both the buttons itself..

Comment: Sorry, maybe I didnt explain it well. Read the top comment please.